# SQL left join with where clause leaving out the empty field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables. A Users table and a Token table. I am trying to join these tables to see who has verified their tokens and who hasn't. The token table has a foreign key with the user id in it.

Right now I am doing a left join on the user ids and trying to check if there is no verification. It looks like this:

```
SELECT name, verified
FROM users LEFT JOIN tokens 
ON users.ID = tokens.UID
WHERE verified = false
```

So if I have the following 2 tables like so:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Joe |
| 1 | Sally |
| 2 | Dave |
| 3 | John |

Then

| ID | UID | Verifed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

As you can see Joe does not have a record in the second table. I want to join the tables and even though Joe doesn't have a record in the I would like that to basically count as false/null. When I run my query searching for unverified users I get the following data with only 2 entries.

| Name | Verified |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | 0 |
| Dave | 0 |

If I take out the where clause I get something like the following:

| Name | Verified |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | 0 |
| Dave | 0 |
| John | 1 |
| Joe | NULL |

As you can see Joe is at the bottom with a null value but I would like to count this somehow as being unverified. How would I write a query that would result in me getting the following data.

| Name | Verified |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | 0 |
| Dave | 0 |
| Joe | NULL |

Or even just the following to result in a count of 3. Right now it would come back as a count of 2.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM users LEFT JOIN tokens 
ON users.ID = tokens.UID
WHERE verified = false
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved. We don't know which table `verified` belongs to...

Comment: @jarlh not sure what you mean here. Verified belongs to the tokens table. Which is the second table specified.

Comment: Then you should write `WHERE tokens.verified = ...`. Anyway, move that condition to the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` result. As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: @jarlh I see yes in my actual code I use tokens.verified I was just trying to keep it simple for demo purposes. I think mysql actually complains a little if you leave it ambiguous. Also so you mean moving the where clause to something like `ON users.ID = tokens.UID AND (tokens.verified = false OR tokens.verified is NULL)`. I think that's proper syntax I am obviously no expert on sql. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE verified = false or verified is null
```

Comment: Using `OR` in a `WHERE` clause can prevent use of indexes on that column. If the OP only needs the count (as implied at the end of the question) then using `NOT EXISTS` can give significantly improved performance.

Comment: I tried doing `verified = false and verified = NULL` but that didn't work but `is NULL` works. Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather do: `ON users.ID = tokens.UID AND tokens.verified = false`

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` clauses are applied *after* the `JOIN`s are completed, by which time the values are potentially `NULL` already.

What you need can be rephrased as `where there ISN'T a token with verified = 1` (Known as an anti-join.)

This can be achieved with `NOT EXISTS`, which (unlike `OR` or `COALESCE`) allows maximal use of indexes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM users
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
     FROM tokens 
    WHERE tokens.UID = users.ID
      AND tokens.verified = true
 )
```

Answer (score -1):

You are so very close to what you need! COALESCE takes a list of variable/values and will output the first non-null result.

So why do we need COALESCE? When doing a left join usually we will show all values even those without a match. However in your WHERE clause you have added `WHERE verified = false`

Verified is a field unique to the tokens table and so when we put that condition it essentially removes our LEFT Join as we must now match the condition.

This is when our COALESCE comes into play. If we were to type `COALESCE(verified, false)` then if verified was NULL we would get false instead. This would make the WHERE clause
`WHERE COALESCE(verified, false) = false`

EDIT: I just reread your question and might also suggest using COALESCE as part of the SELECT itself. COALESCE can be used in either WHERE or SELECT and in if you use it in the SELECT then your Null verified result will display as false.

***Now this isn't the only solution to your problem***

If you instead desired that we have NULL displayed then we must modify our WHERE to include NULL as an option. To do so simply add an `OR verified IS NULL` so that you have `WHERE verified = false OR verified IS NULL`

Comment: Using coalesce will obfuscate any index, and introduce a massive performance penalty.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to list all users and see if they are verified or not, use query:

```
SELECT name, ifnull(verified,0) verified
FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN tokens ON users.ID = tokens.UID;
```

If you want to have only non-verified users, use:

```
SELECT name, verified
FROM (
 SELECT name, ifnull(verified,0) verified
 FROM users 
   LEFT JOIN tokens ON users.ID = tokens.UID
 WHERE verified=0 or verified is null
) AS q;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2F4zsJ9vxXK1jotBcePA9T/0)

Comment: Using IFNULL has the exact same problem as using COALESCE; It obfuscates any index on that column and dramatically limits the optimiser's options.

Comment: @MatBailie, if you want to have a query that answers the orginal question "see who has verified their tokens and who hasn't." one needs to do a table scan for user. The foreign key index on `tokesns` is used to match the tables. There is no info in the question about index on `verified`. The `IFNULL` in first example has no effect on the query optimization.

Comment: Then you'd be better off doing `WHERE x = 0 OR x IS NULL`

Answer (score -4):

AS verified is in tokens table your query should be as follows...

```
SELECT a.name, b.verified FROM users as a LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT UID, verified FROM tokens 
WHERE verified = false) as b ON a.ID = b.UID
```

Comment: This will include all users, regardless of verified flag. The op wants to exclude users that have verified=true.

Comment: Have you checked it? the LEFT JOIN has a clause "verified = false" inside the sub query so users that have verified=true is already excluded

Comment: You have `users LEFT JOIN (tokens WHERE verified = false)`. That means every user is included, that's the point of outer (LEFT) joins. If you changed it to an INNER join, only users with FALSE tokens would be included, but the OP also wants users without a row in the tokens table. (So, in short, have ***you*** tested it?)